# can't delete single article with rails sample project, which destroy will still make GET method in rails 7.0

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I was new to rails 7.0 as I followed the official guide in website, making the sample blog project.

When comes to the delete single post function. Seems my code still fires a GET HTTP request instead of a DELETE request.
I only have one controller which is articles_controller.rb

```rb
  class ArticlesController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @articles = Article.all
  end

  def show
    @article = Article.find(params[:id])
  end

  def new
    @article = Article.new
  end

  def create
    @article = Article.new(article_params)

    if @article.save
      redirect_to @article
    else
      render :new, status: :unprocessable_entity
    end
  end

  def edit
    @article = Article.find(params[:id])
  end

  def update
    @article = Article.find(params[:id])

    if @article.update(article_params)
      redirect_to @article
    else
      render :edit, status: :unprocessable_entity
    end
  end

  def destroy
    @article = Article.find(params[:id])
    @article.destroy

    redirect_to root_path
  end

  private
    def article_params
      params.require(:article).permit(:title, :body)
    end
end
```

My show.html.erb file was like:

```html
<h1><%= @article.title %></h1>
<p><%= @article.body %></p>

<ul>
  <li><%= link_to "Edit", edit_article_path(@article) %></li>
  <li><%= link_to "Destroy", article_path(@article),
                  method: :delete,
                  data: { confirm: "Are you sure?" } %></li>
</ul>
```

UPDATE:
my routes.rb was like

```rb
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  root "articles#index"
  resources :articles
  # Define your application routes per the DSL in https://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html

  # Defines the root path route ("/")
  # root "articles#index"
end
```

also when I perform  `bin/rails routes` in terminal the output was like:

```
 Prefix Verb   URI Pattern                                                                                       Controller#Action
                                    root GET    /                                                                                                 articles#index
                                articles GET    /articles(.:format)                                                                               articles#index
                                         POST   /articles(.:format)                                                                               articles#create
                             new_article GET    /articles/new(.:format)                                                                           articles#new
                            edit_article GET    /articles/:id/edit(.:format)                                                                      articles#edit
                                 article GET    /articles/:id(.:format)                                                                           articles#show
                                         PATCH  /articles/:id(.:format)                                                                           articles#update
                                         PUT    /articles/:id(.:format)                                                                           articles#update
                                         DELETE /articles/:id(.:format)                                                                           articles#destroy
        turbo_recede_historical_location GET    /recede_historical_location(.:format)                                                             turbo/native/navigation#recede
        turbo_resume_historical_location GET    /resume_historical_location(.:format)                                                             turbo/native/navigation#resume
       turbo_refresh_historical_location GET    /refresh_historical_location(.:format)                                                            turbo/native/navigation#refresh
           rails_postmark_inbound_emails POST   /rails/action_mailbox/postmark/inbound_emails(.:format)                                           action_mailbox/ingresses/postmark/inbound_emails#create
              rails_relay_inbound_emails POST   /rails/action_mailbox/relay/inbound_emails(.:format)                                              action_mailbox/ingresses/relay/inbound_emails#create
           rails_sendgrid_inbound_emails POST   /rails/action_mailbox/sendgrid/inbound_emails(.:format)                                           action_mailbox/ingresses/sendgrid/inbound_emails#create
     rails_mandrill_inbound_health_check GET    /rails/action_mailbox/mandrill/inbound_emails(.:format)                                           action_mailbox/ingresses/mandrill/inbound_emails#health_check
           rails_mandrill_inbound_emails POST   /rails/action_mailbox/mandrill/inbound_emails(.:format)                                           action_mailbox/ingresses/mandrill/inbound_emails#create
            rails_mailgun_inbound_emails POST   /rails/action_mailbox/mailgun/inbound_emails/mime(.:format)                                       action_mailbox/ingresses/mailgun/inbound_emails#create
          rails_conductor_inbound_emails GET    /rails/conductor/action_mailbox/inbound_emails(.:format)                                          rails/conductor/action_mailbox/inbound_emails#index
                                         POST   /rails/conductor/action_mailbox/inbound_emails(.:format)                                          rails/conductor/action_mailbox/inbound_emails#create
       new_rails_conductor_inbound_email GET    /rails/conductor/action_mailbox/inbound_emails/new(.:format)                                      rails/conductor/action_mailbox/inbound_emails#new
      edit_rails_conductor_inbound_email GET    /rails/conductor/action_mailbox/inbound_emails/:id/edit(.:format)                                 rails/conductor/action_mailbox/inbound_emails#edit
           rails_conductor_inbound_email GET    /rails/conductor/action_mailbox/inbound_emails/:id(.:format)                                      rails/conductor/action_mailbox/inbound_emails#show
                                         PATCH  /rails/conductor/action_mailbox/inbound_emails/:id(.:format)                                      rails/conductor/action_mailbox/inbound_emails#update
                                         PUT    /rails/conductor/action_mailbox/inbound_emails/:id(.:format)                                      rails/conductor/action_mailbox/inbound_emails#update
                                         DELETE /rails/conductor/action_mailbox/inbound_emails/:id(.:format)                                      rails/conductor/action_mailbox/inbound_emails#destroy
new_rails_conductor_inbound_email_source GET    /rails/conductor/action_mailbox/inbound_emails/sources/new(.:format)                              rails/conductor/action_mailbox/inbound_emails/sources#new
   rails_conductor_inbound_email_sources POST   /rails/conductor/action_mailbox/inbound_emails/sources(.:format)                                  rails/conductor/action_mailbox/inbound_emails/sources#create
   rails_conductor_inbound_email_reroute POST   /rails/conductor/action_mailbox/:inbound_email_id/reroute(.:format)                               rails/conductor/action_mailbox/reroutes#create
rails_conductor_inbound_email_incinerate POST   /rails/conductor/action_mailbox/:inbound_email_id/incinerate(.:format)                            rails/conductor/action_mailbox/incinerates#create
                      rails_service_blob GET    /rails/active_storage/blobs/redirect/:signed_id/*filename(.:format)                               active_storage/blobs/redirect#show
                rails_service_blob_proxy GET    /rails/active_storage/blobs/proxy/:signed_id/*filename(.:format)                                  active_storage/blobs/proxy#show
                                         GET    /rails/active_storage/blobs/:signed_id/*filename(.:format)                                        active_storage/blobs/redirect#show
               rails_blob_representation GET    /rails/active_storage/representations/redirect/:signed_blob_id/:variation_key/*filename(.:format) active_storage/representations/redirect#show
         rails_blob_representation_proxy GET    /rails/active_storage/representations/proxy/:signed_blob_id/:variation_key/*filename(.:format)    active_storage/representations/proxy#show
                                         GET    /rails/active_storage/representations/:signed_blob_id/:variation_key/*filename(.:format)          active_storage/representations/redirect#show
                      rails_disk_service GET    /rails/active_storage/disk/:encoded_key/*filename(.:format)                                       active_storage/disk#show
               update_rails_disk_service PUT    /rails/active_storage/disk/:encoded_token(.:format)                                               active_storage/disk#update
                    rails_direct_uploads POST   /rails/active_storage/direct_uploads(.:format)                                                    active_storage/direct_uploads#create
```

When I click destroy link the server output was like:

```
Started GET "/articles/2" for ::1 at 2022-01-05 15:34:18 +0800
Processing by ArticlesController#show as HTML
  Parameters: {"id"=>"2"}
  Article Load (0.2ms)  SELECT "articles".* FROM "articles" WHERE "articles"."id" = ? LIMIT ?  [["id", 2], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  ↳ app/controllers/articles_controller.rb:7:in `show'
  Rendering layout layouts/application.html.erb
  Rendering articles/show.html.erb within layouts/application
  Rendered articles/show.html.erb within layouts/application (Duration: 0.6ms | Allocations: 92)
  Rendered layout layouts/application.html.erb (Duration: 9.1ms | Allocations: 2366)
Completed 200 OK in 13ms (Views: 10.0ms | ActiveRecord: 0.2ms | Allocations: 3135)


Started GET "/articles/2" for ::1 at 2022-01-05 15:34:29 +0800
Processing by ArticlesController#show as HTML
  Parameters: {"id"=>"2"}
  Article Load (0.2ms)  SELECT "articles".* FROM "articles" WHERE "articles"."id" = ? LIMIT ?  [["id", 2], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  ↳ app/controllers/articles_controller.rb:7:in `show'
  Rendering layout layouts/application.html.erb
  Rendering articles/show.html.erb within layouts/application
  Rendered articles/show.html.erb within layouts/application (Duration: 0.5ms | Allocations: 92)
  Rendered layout layouts/application.html.erb (Duration: 8.5ms | Allocations: 2366)
Completed 200 OK in 13ms (Views: 9.9ms | ActiveRecord: 0.2ms | Allocations: 3140)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rails 7 is using hotwire and turbo instead of Rails/ujs.
So link_to have some problems, **change `link_to` to `button_to`**, it should work.

Comment: Yes, you're right. change ```link_to``` to ```button_to``` works!

**BUT** still after changed into ```button_to``` JS don't prompt the confirmation alert, single blog post deleted directly.

Comment: Check this https://twitter.com/excid3/status/1471241559085617154